# Run Unit Test by command line - Swift Project with cocoaPods

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, jenkins

I'm trying to run a Unit Test from my project using the following command:

```
xcodebuild test -scheme 'WaveIt' -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6,OS=8.4'
```

But I get back this:

> ld: library not found for -lSocketRocket clang: error: linker command
>   failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>
> Testing failed:   Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)
>   ** TEST FAILED **
>
> The following build commands failed:  Ld
>   DerivedData/WaveIt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/WaveIt.app/WaveIt
>   normal x86_64 (1 failure)

My project includes libraries with cocoaPods:

- 'SocketRocket'
- 'Google/Analytics'

And Alamofire (git submodule)

Can anybody tell me what is the problem?

Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify your workspace in xcodebuild.

```
xcodebuild test -workspace 'WaveIt.workspace' -scheme 'WaveIt' -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6,OS=8.4'
```

Comment: The console return me: Testing failed:
 Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
** TEST FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
 Ld DerivedData/WaveIt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/WaveIt.app/WaveIt normal x86_64
(1 failure)

Comment: execute xcodebuild clean and then execute the command xcodebuild test -workspace 'WaveIt.xcworkspace' -scheme 'WaveIt' -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6,OS=8.4' again and the unit test worked!

Comment: I'm glad I could help! :-)